# JTable cell not editing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm using a JTable and I only want columns 0 and 3 to be editable. Column 0 works fine, but when I go to edit column 3, it returns true that it is editable, but does not allow me to enter new text or fire setValueAt(...).

I do have some click events, which I remarked out and using a custom renderer, which I disabled, but nothing seems to help. What else should I look at for a problem? It's not throwing any errors.

Do I need to set a cell editor? I've tried some examples I've found but none seem to work properly. Column 0 is a boolean (checkbox, which works fine) and the rest are strings.

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        //Note that the data/cell address is constant,
        //no matter where the cell appears onscreen.
        if (col == 0) {
            return true;
        }else if(col == 3) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
   
    /*
     * Don't need to implement this method unless your table's
     * data can change.
     */
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                               + " to " + value
                               + " (an instance of "
                               + value.getClass() + ")");
        }

        data[row][col] = value;            
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        int ch;
        int dab;
        try {
            if (col == 0) {
                ch = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(data[row][1]));
                dab = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(data[row][2]))-1;
                plot.dab[ch].get(dab).visible = (boolean) value;
            }
            if (col == 3) {
                ch = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(data[row][1]));
                dab = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(data[row][2]))-1;
                plot.dab[ch].get(dab).desc = String.valueOf(value);
                
            }
            plot.repaintCall();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
      //  System.out.println(ch + "   " + dab);
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("New value of data:");
            printDebugData();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Consider posting a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead of several excerpts of your code. If your excerpts showed the problem you have, someone would have told you about it already.

Comment: Not sure what you are attempting to do. It looks like you attempted to modify the code from the Swing tutorial on "How to Use Tables", but are doing it incorrectly. You say the data is String but you attempt to treat it as Integer. Very confusing. Don't know why you added code to the setValueAt(...) method. That method is used to update the model. The code from the tutorial works fine. The code you added doesn't update the model. Post a proper [mre].